# pd.read_excel ValueError: File is not a recognized excel file

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I can download the .ashx link into .xls and open it manually in Excel:

```
import urllib
urllib.request.urlretrieve(
    'https://www.imf.org/-/media/Files/Publications/WEO/WEO-Database/2022/WEOApr2022all.ashx',
    'weo.xls'
)
```

But when I try reading it with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_excel('weo.xls')
```

it gives error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
> pd.read_excel('weo.xls')
>
> File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util_decorators.py",
> line 299, in wrapper
> return func(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel_base.py", line
> 336, in read_excel
> io = ExcelFile(io, storage_options=storage_options, engine=engine)
>
> File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel_base.py", line
> 1071, in **init**
> ext = inspect_excel_format(
>
> File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel_base.py", line
> 965, in inspect_excel_format
> raise ValueError("File is not a recognized excel file")
>
> ValueError: File is not a recognized excel file

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a csv file separated by tabs and is not exactly a straight forward  dataframe format:

```
pd.read_csv('weo.csv', sep='\t', encoding='utf_16_le')
```

Comment: This command will read the file but the dataframe has just NaNs and no values.

Comment: @qmgm it is because you are using the wrong encoding. I've updated my answer to include the right encoding.